# Using $_GET in class

Tags: php, class, oop

Im learning PHP OOP little by little by myself...

I can't get this to work the way I want, im triying to do this:

http://localhost/test/class.php?action=delete

```
public $action;
public function __construct()
{
        $this->action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null;            
        $this->db = new Db();   
        $this->Select($action);
}

private function Select($action)
{
    if ($action = 'delete') 
    {
            echo "Here";
    }

}

}
```

I think it's pretty basic.. but I can't get the solution by myself.. the screen just goes blank without errors and don't display anything. So i can´t search a solution...

Thank you

Comment: If you get a white screen, enable verbose error reporting. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1)` - obviously not on your production environment...

Comment: Oh god, this is explendid.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `$_GET` in the constructor from your class:

```
Class GetClass {
  public $action;
  public function __construct($get){
      $this->action = isset($get['action']) ? $get['action'] : null;
      $this->db = new Db();   
      $this->Select($this->action);
  }

  private function Select($action){
    if (strtolower($action) == 'delete') {
      echo "Here";
    }
  }

}

$getClass = new GetClass($_GET);
```

Comment: `if ($action = 'delete') {` you need double `=` here... I'd also make it a constant case, ie `strtolower` or `strtoupper`.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Thx didn't notice the single `=`

Comment: Thx, the == wasn't an error, it was while I wrote up everything fast...

Worked perfectly, it was a dumb mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line.

```
 $this->Select($action);
```

to

```
 $this->Select($this->action);
```

and you were also assigning not comparing values within your `if` condition

```
if ($action = 'delete') //assignment operator =
```

should be

```
if ($action == 'delete') //comparison operator ==
```

> **The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).**

[Check Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)